# Multiple process ID in Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, debian, pid

When I check the pid for the chrome I get multiple pid, But in case of the firefox I get only single process id. Why chrome browser uses multiple process ID?

Comment: Because it forks multiple processes.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox and Chrome fundamentally differ on how they operate internally.  Firefox, as you said, has one process ID - because it is one process.  Chrome, however is not.

Chrome uses a [Multi-Process Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Stability).  This isolates each website (tab, etc.) from each other so that they do not affect each other, or the core chrome process, in the event of a failure.  So, if on firefox you have a page that dies, it could cause firefox as a whole to give up and crash. On chrome, however, it is much more likely that only that particular tab will crash, leaving the rest of your tabs and the program as a whole open and running.

Note that this sort of architecture is more difficult to implement and requires more memory.  It is, however, much more stable.

Additional reading material:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation#Web_browsers

http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but looking logically this is the most reasonable answer I came up with:
Processes are quite intense on computer resources. Google possibly has chosen to divide the work over processes rather than threads as Firefox most likley has done. It is just an implementation consideration that was made both Mozilla and Google.
See: http://www.differencebetween.net/miscellaneous/difference-between-thread-and-process/

EDIT:
If you want a more thorough explanation, I would suggest looking at docs of both programs:
http://www.chromium.org/Home
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web

Also checkout this forum discussion: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=702985

Comment: I disagree with "processes are quite intense on computer resources" - the difference between thread and process cost is minimal in modern linux, though perhaps IPC cost may make a difference depending on your application architecture. Additionally a process crash will not necessarily crash an entire application, unlike threads. I believe Chrome uses processes for that exact reason, sandboxing and stability.

Comment: +1 totally true. IPC may indeed be costly using processes may reduce risks in crashing the whole app.